Dimension of invariants in a plethysm of Schur functors
I'm interested in the dimension of $G$-invariants in a composition of Schur functors $\mathbb{S}_{\lambda_1}\circ\ldots\circ \mathbb{S}_{\lambda_k}(\mathbb{C}^n)$ where $G$ is one of the classical Lie groups or Weyl groups (e.g., $\mathrm{GL}_n, \mathrm{O}_n, \mathrm{S}_n$). I know that even for $G=\mathrm{GL}_n$ decomposing such a composition of Schur functors into irreducibles is an open problem known as the problem of plethysm, but I'm wondering if the multiplicity of just the trivial representation is known.
Any ideas or references on this would be much appreciated!

You use the term "plethysm" in your title, a term that I didn't know, and I don't find it in the text of your question...

I am no expert, but for $GL_2$ it is known, and for $GL_n$ in general there is some progress, see for example here. I had also difficulties to see the multiplicities for the trivial module, but this doesn't mean anything (I am doing the Lie algebra case).

@JeanMarie I edited the question to include the term, which refers to composition of Schur functors.

For $GL_n$ there are never any invariants.  Just by degree reasons -- in terms of characters this is asking for the constant term in a homogeneous polynomial of degree $|\lambda_1| \cdot |\lambda_2| \cdots |\lambda_k|$.
